# ARCore render some custom text

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I am using ARCore(OpenGL ES not sceneform) for developing an application about the indoor navigation.
I'm Looking for a simple way to render strings to textures and then draw them within my ARCore session.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/arcore-ml-sample), it might be exactly what you are looking for. It is pure ARCore with ML implementation and they use text renderer for labels

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can i find it also in java ?

Comment: basically I only need to know how to draw a bitmap in the 3D world (so if i understand, i need to create the bitmap mesh)

Comment: i started from helloar sample. So i'm using that classes.